# Firefox displays DRM warning on Azure Media Player without DRM active

Tags: javascript, firefox, azure, drm, azure-media-services

I'm working on an adaptive streaming solution for video out of Azure Media Services. On the client side, I'm using Azure Media Player.

Everything seems to be working fine on all the major browsers. However, Firefox pops up a yellow warning when loading the JS file that drives Microsoft's player. This warning appears even without a `<video>` tag on the page.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Can this be disable? I know I can in my Firefox, but I need my users to not see this warning. As you can see, the video IS playing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When AMP sets up it needs to query the platform capabilities to make a correct decision which tech to use. AMP is simply querying an API if it exists or not.  Firefox, has decided that if you query any DRM support, even if you aren’t using it, you are forced to see this message.  The message itself is a misnomer from Firefox.

This is a known issue and Microsoft is working on it.